# GoogleDrive API & Curl : How to list only my own files

Tags: curl, google-drive-api

I want to list all my files in Google Drive (not the files shared with my, only my own files).

What I'm trying to use : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

I've able to grant OAuth, access token and everything.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Expected result is a list of all my files and the result is a partial list of files shared with me.

Comment: The pageSize of the method of "Files: list" is 100 as the default. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) If there are files and folders of less than 1000 in your Google Drive, you can retrieve the list of all files and folders by one API call with `pageSize=1000`. If there are files and folders of more than 1000 in your Google Drive, it is required to run the method of "Files: list" by the loop with `pageToken`. In this case, several API calls are required. So I think that preparing a script will be useful. If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: In fact, I'm trying to list only my files - and not the files shared with me. But I got more than 1000 files, so this information is helpful in any case. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you may see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#pageSize) of the endpoint, the call has an optional parameter called `pageSize`. That parameter defines the amount of results you will get, and has a default value of 100.

- pageSize parameter (as in the documentation, November 7th 2019)

> The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)

In order to obtain all your results, in case that the amount is lower than 1000 you can just set that parameter to 1000 and obtain all the results. In case it is not, you will have to create a for loop and make several calls. You can see more on how to use pagination on Google APIs in [this link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/pagination).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It will sure helpful as, when it will works, I'll have far more than 1000 results. But for now, I'm still looking for a way to only get a list of my own file and not of the file shared with me.

Comment: @Marc-AntoineDaneau You're welcome!! As for listing only owned files, you just have to add `'me' in owners` to the `q` parameter of the call. The final URL would look as follows: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27me%27%20in%20owners&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`. Cheers

Comment: q parameter : 'me' in owners

Comment: @Marc-AntoineDaneau Correct! :) let me know if you have any other issues, and please consider [accepting/upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer if it was useful to you. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much for replying, it is very helpful and very appreciated. 

That being said, I was on the "recommended" scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file and I was only getting 105 results. So I connected myself to the "restricted" scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive with the hope to be able to reach this famous 1000 results limits. But still, I got 105 results. And I've far more than 2000 files in my drive. I'm using the suggested Q parameter. 
What can I do wrong ?

Comment: Doh! I have forget "pageSize=1000" :) 

Now, next step : pageToken
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Working script here : [Script to list all files in Google Drive : Api, cURL and Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060288/script-to-list-all-files-in-google-drive-api-curl-and-bash)