# Script to list all files in Google Drive : Api, cURL and Bash

Tags: bash, curl, google-drive-api

Here is a bash script using cURL to list all my files from a Google Drive account (not the *shared with me* files, only my own files). You will have to grant access to the Google Drive API in your account and populate, in the script, the variable `$idclient` and `$idsecret` :

```
#!/bin/bash

idclient="Write your ID client between double quote"
idsecret=Write your ID secret here, with no quote

firefox "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id="${idclient}"&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code"

echo "Paste here the code that Google gave you: "
read apptoken

curl --data client_id="${idclient}" --data client_secret="${idsecret}" --data code="${apptoken}" --data redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob --data grant_type=authorization_code https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token > curlID.txt
accesstoken=$(cat curlID.txt | grep 'access_token' | cut -c20-154)
refreshtoken=$(cat curlID.txt | grep refresh_token | cut -c21-123)
cat curlID.txt
rm curlID.txt 

curl  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q=%27me%27%20in%20owners&key="'$idclient'"'  --header 'Authorization: Bearer "'$accesstoken'"' --header 'Accept: application/json'  --compressed > listefichiers_temp.txt

nextPageToken=$(grep nextPageToken listefichiers_temp.txt | sed 's/"nextPageToken": "//' | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.$//' )

echo
echo IDCLIENT :
echo $idclient
echo
echo IDSECRET :
echo $idsecret
echo
echo APPTOKEN :
echo $apptoken
echo
echo ACCESS_TOKEN:
echo $accesstoken
echo
echo REFRESH_TOKEN
echo $refreshtoken
echo
echo NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN:
echo $nextPageToken
echo

cat listefichiers_temp.txt | grep '"id"' | cut -c 11- | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.$//' >> listefichiers.txt
touch log1.txt
cat listefichiers_temp.txt >> log1.txt

### LOOP ###

while grep nextPageToken listefichiers_temp.txt; do
    nextPageToken=$(grep nextPageToken listefichiers_temp.txt | sed 's/"nextPageToken": "//' | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.$//' | cut -c 2- )
    echo NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN
    echo $nextPageToken
    echo
    rm listefichiers_temp.txt
    curl \
       'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&pageToken='$nextPageToken'&q=%27me%27%20in%20owners&key='$idclient'' \
       --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$accesstoken'' \
       --header 'Accept: application/json' \
       --compressed > listefichiers_temp.txt
    cat listefichiers_temp.txt >> log1.txt
    cat listefichiers_temp.txt | grep '"id"' | cut -c 11- | sed 's/.$//' | sed 's/.$//' >> listefichiers.txt
    echo
    echo Nombre de fichiers
    cat listefichiers.txt | wc -l
    echo
    nextPageToken=
done

date
echo Nombre de fichiers
cat listefichiers.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Hopefully you can post 5 lines (or less) of code that reproduce this problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hello Marc-Antoine, could you echo the whole URL inside the while-loop and describe what it outputs? Adding a line such as `echo 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&pageToken='$nextPageToken'&q=%27me%27%20in%20owners&key='$idclient''` should be enough. Cheers

Comment: @shellter : Thanks for the guide. I will use it next time.

I used `sh -xe script.sh` to troubleshoot my script, to follow the advise of @carlesgg97 and now it is working. Thank you! 

I will modify my original post.

Comment: @Lf67VrgB9i1hTd Glad you found your issue! Kindly consider creating an answer to this question briefly explaining how you were able to troubleshoot your issue and what was the modifications that made your code work. Hope to see you around soon again!

Answer (score 1):

Initially, my script was not working. There was an unwanted space at the beginning of `$nextTokenPage` so I add a **cut** at the right place to remove this erroneous space. I was able to troubleshoot the issue while viewing an output of the script with `sh -xe script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

rewritten above solution using jq, added cache for accesstoken, improved fields, etc...

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x

# idclient="Write your ID client between double quote"
# idsecret=Write your ID secret here, with no quote

accesstoken=$(cat accesstoken.txt)

status_code=$(curl -s 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key='$idclient'' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer "'$accesstoken'"' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --compressed \
    --write-out '%{http_code}' \
    --output /dev/null)

if [[ "$status_code" -ne 200 ]] ; then
    open -a "Google Chrome.app" "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id="${idclient}"&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&response_type=code"

    echo "Paste here the code that Google gave you: "
    read apptoken

    accesstoken=$(curl -s --data client_id="${idclient}" --data client_secret="${idsecret}" --data code="${apptoken}" --data redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob --data grant_type=authorization_code https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token | jq -r .access_token)
    echo $accesstoken > accesstoken.txt
fi

# echo
# echo IDCLIENT :
# echo $idclient
# echo
# echo IDSECRET :
# echo $idsecret
# echo
# echo APPTOKEN :
# echo $apptoken
# echo
echo ACCESS_TOKEN:
echo $accesstoken
echo

rm -f fileslist.csv
rm -f log1.txt

### LOOP ###

queryString="%27me%27%20in%20owners%20and%20visibility!%3D%27limited%27%20and%20trashed%3Dfalse"
# queryString="%27me%27%20in%20owners%20and%20trashed%3Dfalse"

curl -s \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q='$queryString'&key='$idclient'&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,webViewLink,parents,shared,permissionIds)' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer "'$accesstoken'"' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --compressed > fileslist_temp.txt
    
while grep nextPageToken fileslist_temp.txt; do
    nextPageToken=$(jq -r .nextPageToken fileslist_temp.txt)
    echo NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN
    echo $nextPageToken
    echo
    # while IFS=, read line; do
    #     id=$(echo $line | jq -r .id)
    #     name=$(echo $line | jq -r .name)
    #     echo "id: $id, name: $name"
    #     curl -s \
    #         'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'$id'/permissions?fields=*' \
    #         --header 'Authorization: Bearer "'$accesstoken'"' \
    #         --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    #         --compressed | jq -c '[.permissions[] | select (.role != "owner") | [.displayName, .type, .emailAddress, .role]]'
    # done < <(jq -c '.files[]' fileslist_temp.txt)
    jq -r '.files[] | [.id, .webViewLink, .parents[], .name, .shared, .permissionIds[]] | @csv' fileslist_temp.txt
    jq -r '.files[] | [.id, .webViewLink, .parents[], .name, .shared, .permissionIds[]] | @csv' fileslist_temp.txt >> fileslist.csv
    cat fileslist_temp.txt >> log1.txt
    echo
    echo Number of Files
    cat fileslist.csv | wc -l
    echo
    curl -s \
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?pageSize=1000&q='$queryString'&key='$idclient'&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,name,webViewLink,parents,shared,permissionIds)&pageToken='$nextPageToken'' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$accesstoken'' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --compressed > fileslist_temp.txt
done

date
echo Number of Files
cat fileslist.csv | wc -l
```